# Problem during removal of disutils-generated RPM

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm, setup.py, distutils

I have recently created a very simple RPM based on distutils (setup.py). When I do `python setup.py bdist_rpm` it generates the RPM normally.

The problem happens when, after I have installed this RPM, if I uninstall it, it doesn't remove the "/usr/lib/python3/site-packages/mylib" folders. Looking into it I can see all __pycache__ folders being left behind empty. Also, the ".egg-info" directories are still there.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name = "mylib",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "An awesome developer",
    description = "An awesome library",
    packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers = [ 
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3", 
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2", 
    ],  
)
```

I do understand that the bdist_rpm command from distutils allows a "postun" script to be set. But shouldn't the generated RPM be responsible for cleaning up its own mess? Am I doing something wrong with the distutils environment?

Comment: The section on Byte Compiling within the [Fedora Python Packaging Guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Python/) might help.

Comment: It's an integration problem between setuptools and rpm. setup.py records the files it's installing into a temporary build artefact called "INSTALLED_FILES". This ends up as %files section of the .spec file. Both setuptools and rpm behave as advertised and together create a bad quality .rpm.

Comment: Does anybody have a workaround yet?